# BSpline Approximation Using MathDotNet

Tags: c#, approximation, math.net, bspline

Does MathDotNet have any capability about data approximations by using b-splines? Unfortunately i couldn't find anything in the documentations!

Comment: It has [cubic splines](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Interpolation/CubicSpline.htm)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any other ways or other libraries for this purpose?

Comment: [ILNumerics](http://ilnumerics.net/ilnumerics-interpolation-toolbox.html#) which you download from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ILNumerics/)